# How does decision tree decide which variable to use in next split?

Tags: cart, rpart

The CART (or RPART) algorithm uses gini index to find a threshold value for a variable in each split. But how does it choose which variable will it use for splitting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It tries all of them and the one with the lowest gini is used.